# How to set up multiple image targets (not necessarily simultaneously) with vuforia and unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I can setup a project in unity using vuforia with a single image target displaying a single 3D animation.

I've also seen a few tutorials on how to set up a project in unity with vuforia to track up to 5 image targets simultaneously.

How can I set up a project in unity using vuforia with multiple (up to 100) image targets that won't be tracked simultaneously? I want to display 100 different 3D images using 100 different image targets.

I know how to create an image target database but how to show a different 3D model for each different image target?

Comment: What is the difference between tracking 5 targets (assuming each has its own graphics to be displayed) and 100? If you can track 5 targets, simultaneously or not, you can track 100 not simultaneously...

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between tracking 5 targets and 100 targets.
All you need to do is adding 100 `ImageTarget` prefabs to your scene and then 100 different 3D models under each `ImageTarget`. It will be painful, but it will work.

You can also look at the Cloud Recognition functionality in this scope and of course on MultiTarget prefab.